# React Router - undefined params if previous one is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

This is how my routing looks like:

```
            <Switch>
              ...
              <Route
                path="/search/:searchValue/:who?/:industries?/:area?"
                component={Search}
              />
              ...
            </Switch>
```

Then I've this link (in another component)

```
              <NavLink
                className={classes.appBarLink}
                to={`/search/${input}/${chiCerco}/${industriesSel}/${geoArea}`}
              >
```

I'm filling those data in to="" with a form.
In the next page I'm catching the data with:
`this.props.match.params.who` ... and so on.

Problem is, if "industries" is empty I'm not ablet to get "area".
So I've to fill all the data, all the time.

Is It correct?
The params are actually "optionals" in the URL.

(also the URL from `this.props.match.url` is incomplete if I'm not filling all)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I haven't used optional params for a long time but it makes a lot of sense that router enforces defined path, otherwise it could conflict with other paths. I can think of 2 ways to solve this: use some kind of default value if you have no data or use query string to pass optional data.

Comment: Was thinking about default values... It's working, but It does not seems so good as solution.

Comment: You could also add multiple routes with different `path` values.

Comment: Multiple in the same <Route> component? Have you got an example?

Comment: No, 2 separate routes with same components but only paths are different. Order matters, therefore first route with matching path gets rendered. E.g `/search/:searchValue/:who/:area/:industries?` and `/search/:searchValue/:who/:industries/:area?`

Comment: Another possible solution (Im pretty much shooting in dark here): generic params, e.g `:param1?/:param2?` but prefix you value with actual type, e.g `/search/area-somevalue/industry-somevalue`. Now order doesn't matter, just loop over params and use JS string methods to get the type.

Comment: I'm using default values like "null" ... I think It's ok as value... multiple routes will be my next try If I'll change my mind.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd personally choose values like `none` or `all` but it's you choice. Good luck!